# UI Scaling vs. Screen Resolution on Secondary Monitor

Tags: display, resolution

I have a secondary monitor connected to my MacBook, which has a native resolution of 3440x1440.

When I go into System Settings > Displays the built-in display allows me to set UI scaling, like so:

[image]

But when I select the external display, it only allows me to specify the display resolution, like so:

[image]

How do I set UI scaling rather than resolution for the external display, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The interface controls that Apple shows you for your built-in display, with **"Larger Text" / "More Space"**, is just a simplified version of the list of resolutions.

If you hover your mouse pointer over the buttons, you'll see a resolution value beneath each one.

[image]

If you click on the "Advanced..." button at the bottom of the panel, then there's an option for whether to display the resolutions as a list, or not.

[image]

This seems to only make hi-dpi retina displays shows as lists, but not to make other displays show as the buttons.

On my external display, whatever 'resolution' I choose, it still fills the entire pixel area of the display.  If you choose 2560 x 1080 on your display, the OS still uses all 3440 x 1440 pixels, but it's making that smaller grid spread out over a larger screen, i.e. scaling it by 1.333.

If you switch the "Show all resolutions" switch ON, then you might get some more choices. But where it says "1720 x 720 (HiDPI)" -- that's a 2x scaling.

In short: there's no difference between "UI scaling" and "resolution".

Also, it's possible that macOS shows you different resolutions/scalings, depending on the pixel density of your display. If you display is larger than 27 inches, then some scalings might be less than satisfactory.

Comment: "The interface controls that Apple shows you for your built-in display, with "Larger Text" / "More Space", is just a simplified version of the list of resolutions." - Is this entirely correct? On a 4K display, if I hover over the largest size it displays 1920x1080, but it's not actually setting the resolution to 1920x1080; rather, it's scaling the UI to 200%, effectively a 2:1 pixel ratio, which is how retina displays achieve such sharp images, so I wonder if a 3440x1440 display simply doesn't have the pixel density for UI scaling?

Comment: @MatthewLayton That's exactly what I said: The OS scales the display to "map" to those resolutions, which in effect scales the size of the interface. The same thing will happen on your 3440 display; it's just that it might look blurry, because of the lower pixel density.